# Eclipse rcp show different layout in Launch and exported file

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-rcp

I'm using Eclipse Luna for creating RCP Application. I set product configuration file for plug-in project. When I run application by click Launch button (Launch an Eclipse application) from Overview page, (1) it keep show old code, not changed one.
So, I exported my application. The first time works find and then second time this one also doesn't show changed codes. I have to remove folder every time for checking updated codes.

Please, someone help me to figure out these issues. It's really bugging me.

1. Keep showing old code from Launch an Eclipse application & Eclipse Product export wizard
2. Launch and exported file show different layout

[image]

From Launch

[image]

From exported file.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: If you are changing the perspective layout then, yes, you have to clear the workspace metadata to get the perspective changes.

Comment: Yes, I'm changing the perspective layout. how can I clear the workspace metadata? Even click launch buttom need to be clear everytime?

Comment: I remove the metadata from exported folder. It couldn't show updated code either.

Answer (score 0):

I found to run with updated source after exported files. Do uncheck "Generate p2 repository" & "Allow for binary cycles in target platform" when opened Export dialog. After unchecked it them I could get updated files. It looks it happened for application version managing (P2 Folder).